# La tabla ya esta creada ¿como not null cambiarla a null? en laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, doctrine2

Tengo varios archivos de migración.
Esto archivos se migraron. Y ya tienen muchos datos.
Quiero cambiar una columna existente `doctors.email` que ahora esta como `not null`, quiero cambiarla a `null`.

Este es el código que le puse al nuevo archivo de migración:

```
Schema::table(‘doctors’, function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->string(‘email’)->nullable()->change();
});
```

¿Esta bien creado este código?

Resulta que al ejecutar `php artisan migrate` me da un error.

> Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException  : Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.

Y lo raro, es que si en ves de tener la migración que les mencione(cambiar de `not null` a `null`) realizo una migracion (solo para probar) como por ejemplo agregar un usuario.

```
2019_07_12_204509_add_null__value_to_doctors_table.php
```

Me la crea y no da error.

Las dudas que tengo son, ¿Laravel vuelve a parsear las migraciones que ya fueron migradas?, es decir, que están en la base de datos, en la tabla migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error conocido de Doctrine, está documentado desde hace un buen tiempo con las posibles soluciones:

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3161

En todo caso, en la documentación de Laravel está especificado (parcialmente) que las tablas con campos `enum` no pueden ser modificadas:

> Renaming any column in a table that also has a column of type enum is not currently supported.
>
> Only the following column types can be "changed": bigInteger, binary, boolean, date, dateTime, dateTimeTz, decimal, integer, json, longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time, unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger and unsignedSmallInteger.

En una pregunta de SO en inglés sugieren esta solución, que al parecer funciona:

```
public function __construct()
{
    DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()
        ->getDatabasePlatform()
        ->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
}
```

Consiste en agregar este código a la migración, el cual mapeará las columnas enum a varchar, para que la columna acepte cualquier valor.